# How to reuse GitHub sign up for stackoverflow.com on other Stack Exchange communities?

Tags: support, accounts

I signed up to stackoverflow.com via GitHub.

Now I realize the other Stack Exchange communities do not offer this option. However, I would like to use the stackoverflow.com account for other Stack Exchange sites as well.

How can I achieve this? 
Can I register with Google and then merge the different accounts? 
Or do I have to register separately for each site?

Comment: This is not off topic, especially as they cannot post on meta.stackexchange.com either

Answer (score 7):

I solved it by making a "forgot password" request on stackexchange.com using the GitHub email address.

Now I can login on every different Stack Exchange community using that password.

Comment: That's just dumb though. Why on earth do we have support for a SSO if said SSO can't be used network-wide? It's an SE account with extra steps and next to no uses at that point

Comment: @Zoe it has been like this [since 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67221/241919)  when Ubuntu.SE got Launchpad SSO exclusively...

Comment: This does not work for me :( I says unknown email address